# PhoneGap: How to set Build and Version Property in Config.xml for iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova

An iOS app has a version an a build number. When using config.xml of a PhoneGap/Cordova project I can set

```
<widget id="bundlename" version="1.1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

This property sets the version as well as the build to 1.1.0.

**Is there a way to set the version and build number separately in the config.xml?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
</widget>

<!-- Android -->
<widget versionCode="0.1.3">
</widget>

<!-- iOS -->
<widget CFBundleVersion="0.1.3">
</widget>

<!-- Windows -->
<widget packageVersion="0.1.3">
</widget>
```

From https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/config_ref/index.html#widget.

Comment: Hey hi, doing this in the config.xml file, when building it using "phonegap build android", it gives error : ``` [phonegap] executing 'cordova build android ' ...
Error: Cannot read property 'replace' of null```

Comment: how can I change version="0.0.1" for ios and android separately. And I think its now versionCode for android, its android-versionCode and it takes integer only not dots value.